# .change() only running once and not at click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I've got a JS file that's automatically run through an HTML script. A function putToggleCall() is supposed to run every time one of the many toggles is clicked but instead it only runs once, before the document is even ready(based on my other functions). I know this from the console.log() inside my function. The goal is to simplify the code so that all the bootstrap toggles can use one PUT call function on change (i.e. onclick).

```
var toggles = {
    "#rando": "random/url",
    etc..
};

function putToggleCall(toggle_id) {
    var value = $(toggle_id).prop("checked") ? 1:0;
    console.log(value)
    $.ajax({
        url: BASE_URL + toggles[toggle_id],
        type: "PUT"
    }).done(
    ).fail(function(data,textStatus,errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown);
    });
  };
 for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(toggles).length;i++) {
    var toggle_id = Object.keys(toggles)[i]
    $(toggle_id).change(putToggleCall(toggle_id));
 })
```

Answer (score 2):

You're calling the function, not referencing it.

You either need a wrapping anonymous function

```
$(toggle_id).change(function() {
    putToggleCall(toggle_id)
});
```

or just reference the function

```
$(toggle_id).change(putToggleCall);
```

and find another way to pass the data *(hint: it's available as `this.id`, or even just `this` in the function)*

Comment: this worked, but then when I use the same structure on another js file (I have separate js files for each nav tab) it goes back to only running when the page loads. So now I have the first page that still works and another, identical except for function names, that doesn't.